# What's the easiest way to download the source of a webpage in python? (After javascript has been applied)

Tags: javascript, python, html, http, rest

In python:

I want to download the source of a webpage, after the javascript has been applied.  What's the easiest way to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`splinter`](http://splinter.cobrateam.info/) is the easiest way to do this:

```
from splinter.browser import Browser
browser = Browser()
browser.visit('http://google.com')
```

`splinter` is a tool that makes using several mature products much easier to use. Things like Selenium require lots of getting used to. `splinter` allows you to learn one API to use the webdriver or change to zope.testbrowser if you would like to.

You can run JavaScript and alter the page or test its results:

```
browser.execute_script("$('body').empty()")
browser.evaluate_script("4+4") == 8
```

Comment: Does it work with cookies? For example, can I log into Facebook using this?  Also, let's say that on $function(){ $("div.test").html("abc") } ; I can get a string (the source code) with <div class="test">abc</div> right?

Comment: This blog post discusses logging into Facebook http://www.franciscosouza.com/2011/05/splinter-python-tool-for-acceptance-tests-on-web-applications/

Comment: +1 Surprisingly useful answer. Opens an universe of possibilities. Is facebook nothing but a flock of sprinter bots?